# Html 5 formdata file upload issue with asp.net webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, web-services, iis

I'm having an strange issue with html5 formdata. i'm using the html5 form data to send a file to the server via jquery ajax request. then using asp.net webservice to receive the posted file and saving the file to a directory.

This process worked fine locally. once i published to the server I'm getting an   internal server error 500.

once I ran the website locally inside the sever its working. I think the issue with  web server cant access the client path?

```
  var formData = new FormData();

  for (var i = 0; i < uploadFileArray.length; i++) {

        var f = uploadFileArray[i];   
            formData.append('file' + i, f.file);
    }

    formData.append('indexdate', indexDate);
    formData.append('status', status);
    formData.append('category', category);
    formData.append('comments', comments ? comments : '');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () { $defer.notify(); },
        success: function (response) {

            $defer.resolve(response)
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            $defer.reject(textStatus);

        }
    });
```

Web Service

```
      <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function UploadFiles() As String

    Try
         Dim postedContext As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current            

        Dim indexDate As String = postedContext.Request.Form("indexdate")

        Dim status As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(postedContext.Request.Form("status"))

        Dim docCategoryKey As String = postedContext.Request.Form("category")

        Dim comments As String = postedContext.Request.Form("comments")

        ' Get the file collection 

        Dim request As HttpFileCollection = postedContext.Request.Files

        For Each filename As String In request

            Dim file As HttpPostedFile = request(filename)

            'Validate the data

            If file Is Nothing Then
                Throw New System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Please upload a valid file")
            End If

            SaveFiles(file, docCategoryKey, comments, status, indexDate)

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
    Return ""
End Function
```

Comment: what is your `serviceUrl`? Try giving a fully qualified name once!!

Comment: You mean absolute URL? But I'm not getting 404 error.

Comment: Yea but how is it like?? can you post it??

Comment: Its not working, but its working when i use locally(with out absolute URL). even if i run that website in the sever with local host its working fine. do i have to specify the content-Type in the ajax call?

Comment: if you are posting `formdata`. No. `ContentType` has to be `false`. Did you just check for any console.errors while trying in server??

Comment: In the web service i just tried a default HelloWorld method, but its still showing the 500 error, once i changed to content type "application/json" it is working.

Comment: But I think you won't get your `formdata` when you change your `content type`! Are you??

Comment: yes. but i tried with the native xhr call, still throwing the same 500 error. i couldn't to get the specific error message. can you please tell me how can i return a specific error message?

Comment: `xhr.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
    Console.log(xhr + ' ' + textStatus + ' ' +error);
});`  It will be usually internal server error..

Comment: I fixed that issue with changes in web config file https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/819267/